# SwiftUI lifecycle of view regarding to variables

Tags: swift, swiftui

How does the lifecycle of a SwiftUI View work, regarding storage?

I understand the implications of using `@State`, `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject`, `@Binding` and even a simple `let/var`

but not how the storage lifecycle works and how it is associated to the above variables

**What gives a View it's identity and how does the system knows, when new View instances must be created and when they are only reassigned to this particular created View struct**

I found this to be the key to understanding, whats actually going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty big subject, and not one that easily fits into a StackOverflow post.

I think a lot of your questions come up in the **Data Essentials in SwiftUI** session from WWDC 2020. It goes into some of the internals of how SwiftUI works that will go a long way to helping your understanding.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040

Comment: this talk was GOLD... explained it all